# Win 10 Universal App with Cordova trying to load flash

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, windows-10-universal

I'm building a cross-platform Cordova app with Visual Studio 2015 and tools for Apache Cordova. Therefore I'm using the Blank Cordova App (with TypeScript) from Tools for Apache Cordova.
Everything seems to work fine, except there is a strange error in the JavaScript Console when running the App on Windows 10:

> APPHOST9603: "Can’t load the ActiveX plug-in that has the class ID "{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}". Apps can't load ActiveX controls."

This is kind of strange because I'm not unsing any ActiveX plug-in. At least not knowingly... The error is also only visible when running the app on Windows.

Googling the UID brought me [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737898%28v=ws.10%29.aspx): It is some sort of configuration for Shockwave Flash, which I'm not using either.

One can reproduce the error by creating a new project with the template, changing the desired Windows platform in the config.xml to Windows 10 and starting debugging on a local Windows 10 PC.

Do you have any idea on how to resolve this error? Might this be a bug?

Edit: Same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900642/cordova-admob-apphost9603-error?lq=1).

Edit: Here is the initially created index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <title>BlankCordovaApp1</title>

    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <p id="deviceready" class="event">Connecting to Device</p>
    </div>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/appBundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this normal that I cant open the website https://ssl.gstatic.com/ on my chrome web browser? Is this happening since I am in a private network now, maybe?

Comment: I guess it is normal, according to the [documentation](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/cordova-5-security/#the-csp-in-cordova-5) the reference is only there to make Android TalkBack-functionality work.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the steps you provided. what happens if you create a project without typescript? have you installed the latest updated vs tools for apache Cordova 7? The update installation may help us to repair the tool and fix some known issue.

Comment: if the issue still occurs in a blank new project on your side, you can send the project to your friend or share with me. I can check if something unexpected is embedded into the project.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN Says (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj860457.aspx):

> Windows Runtime apps using JavaScript don't support custom Microsoft
>   ActiveX controls. If you need a UI control, use an HTML control, a
>   Windows Library for JavaScript control, or create your own custom
>   WinJS control. If you need to perform custom logic, create a custom
>   Windows Runtime object instead.

It seems like in your frame, the plug-in ActiveX is used. If you are referencing a webpage and if the webpage is using shockwave flash, it might cause the problem. According to MSDN, it is not possible display a page which contains ActiveX plugin in Windows. Since you are not providing a code, I cannot exactly specify the reason, but this is my best guess.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my edit i tried to point out that it seems not to be a code problem, you can reproduce the error without writing a line of code. I do not reference any webpage except the initial index.html, which i will add to my originial question

Answer (score -3):

Simple answer: You can't use Flash player in that environment.

Reason: You can not use ActiveX components from Windows Store apps.