# Cordova Admob AppHost9603 Error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, admob, visual-studio-cordova

I can't seem to get AdMob integrated with my Ionic Cordova app, I am receiving an AppHost9603 error and not seeing any ads. I am using the AdMobPro plugin. Here's what I've done:

1. In Visual Studio I have added the AdMobPro plugin installed by providing the git path in config.xml->custom->git path
2. I have added the file admob_simple.js in my js folder following the documentation
3. I have added a reference in index.html to the js file like this

> This is in index.html -

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/admob_simple.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

4. I am running on my local machine, not an emulator. Error says APPHOST9603: Can’t load the ActiveX plug-in that has the class ID '{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}'.  Apps can't load ActiveX controls.
   index.html
5. And I see no ads

Can you help? And thank you

Comment: I'm seeing the [same error without admob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840922/win-10-universal-app-with-cordova-trying-to-load-flash). Maybe it's rather a Cordova or a Windows 10 UAP Problem. Are you running the app as a Windows 10 Universal App?

Comment: Maybe not admob specifically then but maybe with Cordova or plugins. I have code I can pull before adding the admobpro plugin and can run Windows 10 UAP local without errors. Add the plugin, do nothing else, run again - two of these errors happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the same error.

I think that is because the Admob still doesn't support Windows 10(maybe only windows phone 8 supported), since I only saw the following in https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

[image]

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately Windows 10 still isn't supported. Got it running on Android. Hint to others using Visual Studio, make sure you have your packages installed and updated from the separate Android SDK Manager program for Google Services.