# Cordova Windows 10 App Apps can't load ActiveX controls

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-10-universal

This is a very similar problem to this
[Win 10 Universal App with Cordova trying to load flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840922/win-10-universal-app-with-cordova-trying-to-load-flash)

This app was running fine around 3 weeks ago. It loads video from a CDN, and this seems to be related to the problem.

The error is showing 4 times and seems to stop the video from playing.

> APPHOST9603: Can’t load the ActiveX plug-in that has the class ID
>   '{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}'.  Apps can't load ActiveX
>   controls.

There is also an error when it tries to load Fonts.. so I assume it's related.

There is no ActiveX plugins or anything else being used. It's all HTML5 with WebGL.  I don't think I've updated Visual Studio or changed anything.

It makes no sense as to where this has come from.

Comment: Could you maybe share a demo that can reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's gone away. I'm not sure what it is, but it might have been a security issue, I removed the cross-domain attribute of the video and it seemed to solve it.